# Средство для комфортного изменения контента html

Tags: html, site

Грубо говоря есть сайт, в котором все странички - статичные html на английском. Я бы хотел это перевести, но прежде чем окунуться в emacs и скакать по тегам, исправляя содержимое, хотелось бы узнать, нет способа поудобнее?
К примеру, в моем представлении, это программка, которая преобразует html в страничку как сайт, но с возможность редактирования текста непосредственно на этой странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить воспользоваться devTools браузера на базе хромиума (Chrome, Яндекс.Браузер, ...) в режиме designMode. Для этого **откройте инструменты разработчика** (F12 или alt+cmd+i). Далее выберите вкладку **Console**. Наберите в консоли

```
document.designMode = 'on'
```

После этого вы сможете править текст прямо на странице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Изображение из статьи https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=311582*